# Create Project Web Application Site With Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-project

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Project Web App site (for Project Server 2010) using Powershell commands, and I'm running into an error that I haven't been able to find any help on. Here's what I'm doing (using the commands found here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890097%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

1. Create the Project Service Application

   ```
   New-SPProjectServiceApplication –Name "MS Project" –ApplicationPool "MS Project App Pool" –Proxy
   ```
2. Create the Project Service Application Proxy (note, I do this seperately, because using the "-Proxy" parameter from above doesn't appear to work)

   ```
   New-SPProjectServiceApplicationProxy -Name "MS Project Application Proxy" -ServiceApplication "MS Project"
   ```
3. Create the Project Web Instance (this is the part that fails, error message to follow)

   ```
   New-SPProjectWebInstance -Url "http://[server name]/pwa" -AdminAccount "[admin account]" -PrimaryDbserver "[database server]" -PublishedDbname "ProjectServer_Published" -ArchiveDbname "ProjectServer_Archive" -DraftDbname "ProjectServer_Draft" -ReportingDbserver "[database server]" -ReportingDbname "ProjectServer_Reporting" -Wait
   ```

Error Message:

```
New-SPProjectWebInstance : The HTTP service located at http://[server name]:32843/cc3a25ad34b94072936ec29f8bd10591/PSI/psiserviceapp.svc is too busy.
At line:1 char:25
+ New-SPProjectWebInstance <<<<  -Url "http://[server name]/pwa" -AdminAccount "[admin account]" -PrimaryDbserver "[database server]"
-PublishedDbname "ProjectServer_Published" -ArchiveDbname "ProjectServer_Archive" -DraftDbname "ProjectServer_Draft" -ReportingDbserver "[database server]" -ReportingDbname "ProjectServer_Reporting" -Wait
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...tNewPwaInstance:PSCmdletNewPwaInstance) [New-SPProjectWebInstance], ServerTooBusyExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Cmdlet.PSCmdletNewPwaInstance
```

I found an article (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariae/archive/2012/10/30/the-http-service-located-at-http-machine-32843-a49407bfb2c3432e9953dc831d8b0a0f-reportingwebservice-svc-is-too-busy.aspx) that suggested getting an instance of the Service Application and re-provisioning it before attempting to create the Web Instance (see code below), but that didn't help either...still got the same error message from Step 3 above. Note: the commands in that article are slightly different, as they deal with Reporting Services rather than Project Server, but the concept *should* be the same.

```
    $spapp = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "MS Project"
    $spapp.Provision()
```

Is there some other step I am missing? I've tried waiting after steps 1 & 2 to see if maybe it was something that needed to be done "at a certain time" so to speak, but not had any luck. Also, after steps 1 & 2 I can go into Manage Service Applications in Central Admin and successfully create the site...I'm just having no such luck doing it with Powershell (and I would like to completely script this process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution on my own. Turns out, during the removal process, I had not removed and recreated the Application Pool for the Project Service Application...this is a needed step when doing this process through Powershell (and, according to Microsoft, the example on TechNet don't work, because they don't mention this needed step).

So, Prior to Step 1 above, you need to run:

```
New-SPServiceApplicationPool  -Name "MS Project App Pool" -Account "[admin account]"
```

And this also elminates the need for Step #2 above...after recreating the Application Pool, the -Proxy switch on the command in Step 1 successfully created the Proxy.